# How should the texture file look like?

Tags: texture

I am wondering why the texture of the following 3D model https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/GoogleResearch/fuel/models/Transformers_Age_of_Extinction_Mega_1Step_Bumblebee_Figure

[image]

Looks like the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Gd0.jpg

How are these logically connected?

Comment: inside each vertex is a 2D texture-coordinate. This allows the Graphics library to interpolate the texture-coordinates of all 3 vertices of each triangle during the rasterization step.

Comment: some more information about the concept of vertex-buffer-objects (VBO) and texturing you can finde here: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

Comment: @Thomas what are all circles in the upper right corner?

Comment: @MonaJalal Probably screws or holes in the model. Texture file you've sent looks perfectly normal. As Thomas said - by following tutorias from learnopengl, you can easily understand how this thing works. For DirectX (even though, in theory it works exactly the same, but you might want to learn this framework) - you can check http://www.rastertek.com/ ; Even though, his style is not the best, his explanation are nice. And there are a lot of tutorials for the start.

Comment: @MonaJalal to figure out at what position in the mesh "model" these small circles are, you can color them lets say in magenta and see where in the model are magenta parts.

Comment: The triangles for a mesh can be overlaid onto the texture by replacing the vertex coordinates with the the UV coordinates and a constant z value (usually zero). Just draw a fullscreen quad with the texture drawn on it, then the triangles for the mesh drawn as a wire frame. Some modeling programs have this overlay method as an option, I don't know if meshlab has this feature or not.